# Validating form password against MySQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, authentication

I'm relatively new to PHP and I'm trying to setup a login system. The part which is causing me trouble is trying to check if the password received from a form matches the corresponding email on a MySQL database (bearing in mind the email address was also submitted on the form). At the moment I am unsure what to do but this is the source code I pulled together...

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "***";
$password = "***";
$dbname = "pearsem_mystore";

// Create Connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check database connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT firstName, userEmail, userPass FROM users WHERE userEmail = '".$_POST["userEmail"]."'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

if ($row["userPass"] == $_POST["userPass"]) {
    // If true... Welcome {firstname}
    echo "Welcome " . $row["firstName"];
} 
elseif ($result->num_rows == 0) {
    echo "Incorrect email address/password";
} 
else {
    echo "Error";
}
$conn->close();

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!
P.S. I have tried to explain the situation as best as possible but if you need more information then please ask.

Comment: You'd need to show the form, and also - is the password stored in plain-text? If that's the case, that's *very* insecure.

Comment: You can read more about password authentication over here http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/530/password-hashing-functions#t=201611192242240823932 . Also you might wanna use a database rather than storing credentials as php variables

Comment: Why don't check the password by mysql itself? `select... where email=... and pass=...`. If this query returns data, then user is authenticated, but you need sanitize all incoming data. Your code is vulnerable for sql-injection.

Comment: Saving raw password to dB? you've got more problem there...

Answer (score -1):

First off:

> If you're storing the raw password in the database, then thats a BIG
>   DON'T.

Use password_hash before you write to dB. Then password_verify when you compare passwords with user inputs.

Three links to help you:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php
- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/124777/using-phps-password-hash-and-password-verify-for-a-login-function